# Does bean method validation 1.1 run in the same transaction as the method

Tags: jakarta-ee, bean-validation, jta

I’m using bean method validation 1.1 on methods in my @Stateless service beans with access to some Entity beans via the EntityManager.
I can inject some other Stateless service beans in the method ConstraintValidator class, and also an EntityManager, that works fine.

1) Do my method validation constraints run in the same transaction as the method from the stateless service bean?

2) If I inject an EntityManager in the ConstraintValidator it is not the same as the one in my Stateless bean method.  How can I access the entityManager/session from the Stateless bean in my validation method so both run in the same session/transaction?

I’m using wildly 8.1.0